# Echo dynamic sed to file inside Dockerfile

Tags: docker, shell, sed, dockerfile, echo

I am working on a Dockerfile, inside of which I want to dynamically create a `sed` expression based on the input argument variable, and write this expression to a file.

Here's part of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG VERSION

RUN echo $VERSION > /usr/local/testfile

RUN echo '#!/bin/sh \n\
sed -i "s/\"version\"/\${VERSION}/g" file' > /usr/local/foo.sh
```

the image builds fine.
When I start a container from that image, and inspect the files:

```
# cat /usr/local/testfile
0.0.1

# cat /usr/local/foo.sh
#!/bin/sh
sed -i "s/\"version\"/\${VERSION}/g" file
```

I notice that the `$VERSION` was not replaced correctly in the `sed` command. What am I missing here? I've tried a few different things (e.g. `"$VERSION"`) but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up breaking down the command. I created a variable for the `sed` command by using string concatenation and then I `echo`ed that to the file separately:

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG VERSION

ENV command="sed -i s/\"version\"/""$VERSION""/g"

RUN echo '#!/bin/sh' > /usr/local/foo.sh
RUN echo $command >> usr/local/foo.sh

# cat /usr/local/foo.sh
#!/bin/sh
sed -i s/"version"/0.0.1/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if all of these requirements is met:

- Docker run command or docker-compose build has defined build arguments
- Dockerfile has loaded build arguments to container environment e.g.:

```
ARG VERSION
ENV VERSION ${VERSION}
```

- sed command script uses double quotes e.g. `sed -i "s/$VERSION/0.0.1/g"`
- used argument name is case sensitively correct